# Finding the length of a character literals(const char *)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

I am not sure about others, but to this day when I want to find out the length of a 
character literals ex:`"somevalue"` I use `strlen()`, now I've been reading a metaprogramming library [Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) which I assume would well known in the C++ community, it has some code to deal with string at compile time and then here is a piece of some code

```
#define BOOST_HANA_STRING(s)                                                \
    (::boost::hana::string_detail::prepare([]{                              \
        struct tmp {                                                        \
            static constexpr decltype(auto) get() { return s; }             \
        };                                                                  \
        return tmp{};                                                       \
    }()))
```

basically what it does is

```
 auto temp = BOOST_HANA_STRING("123");
 constexpr auto sze = sizeof(temp.get())-1; //mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 3
```

Detects the length of the `const char *` at compile time!! how did it happen? I thought the `decltype(auto)` kinda did a trick while deducing the  `return` statement, so I wrote like

```
template<typename constcharstar>
decltype(auto) get(constcharstar ptr) { return ptr; }
constexpr auto sze = sizeof(get("123")); //`mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 8`(64-bit arch)
```

My guess sucks!!, so to figure out  what the `return s` is actually being deduced to, I've used the boost's `type_index.hpp`

```
   auto  G = BOOST_HANA_STRING("abcd");
   cout<<boost::typeindex::type_id<decltype(G.get())>().raw_name();
   Result : which prints `A21_c`
```

My intuition says that the `const char *` is being deduced to an `array of 21 char's` (I could be wrong though)

> Edit : I figured out it is `char [21]` used `pretty_name()`

My question is, how it has got deduced to `char [21]` and why it only works when I wrapped in `struct` but not in a free function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Detects the length of the `const char*` at compile time!! how did it happen?

Well, it doesn't. It detects the size of a `const char[]`. You can try it yourself:

```
const char hello[] = "world";
const auto size = sizeof(hello)-1;
```

Anything else is sugar.

> My question is, how it has got deduced to `char [21]` [...]?

In C++, the type of a string literal is *array of cont char of size X* where *X* is appropriately chosen.

> Why it only works when I wrapped in struct but not in a free function?

It's not about free function vs. struct, it's about macro argument vs. function argument. In `#define BOOST_HANA_STRING(s)`, `return s;` returns a string literal. In `decltype(auto) get(constcharstar ptr)`, `return ptr;` returns an already decayed `const char*`.

Comment: thanks! one more thing to be clear, if the macro were to be written like 
   ` #define BOOST_HANA_STRING(s) `    
           `  []{  `                       
                `return s;` 
               `};  `
and when i do `auto obj = BOOST_HANA_STRING("123");` `constexpr auto s = sizeof(obj());` am getting result `8` which is same as a `ptr`  been passed, it is because  something got to do with the return type `operator()` in lambda?

Comment: A function can only return a reference to an array or a pointer (decayed array). A lamba will always choose the later. That's why the struct trick is needed.

Answer (score 2):

First lets take a look at exactly what

```
#define BOOST_HANA_STRING(s)                                                \
    (::boost::hana::string_detail::prepare([]{                              \
        struct tmp {                                                        \
            static constexpr decltype(auto) get() { return s; }             \
        };                                                                  \
        return tmp{};                                                       \
    }()))
```

is doing.  What it essential does is create an object that has a function that returns the string literal.  If we were to make our own it could look like

```
struct string_size
{
    decltype(auto) get() { return "12"; }
};
```

and if we do

```
std::cout << sizeof(string_size().get());
```

we would get `3`.  This works becuase a string literal has the type `const char[N]`, not `const char *`.  Since it is an array, `decltype(auto)`, gives us a reference to it and `sizeof` will display the correct size of the string literal.

Another way you can do this is to use a template function

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::size_t size(const char (&arr)[N]) { return N; }
```

Does the same kind of thing.  We take the array in by reference and since the size of the array is part of the type we can deduce that and return it.

Comment: NathanOliver what that tripped me is though I figure out it is an array of chars I did things like 

`  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(object.get()),char[21]>::value,"");`

 ` static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(object.get()),const char[21]>::value,"");`

 ` static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(object.get()),char const[21]>::value,"");`

the results are negative, did anything I miss here?

Comment: @Explorer_N You are getting a reference to an array so you need `std::is_same<decltype(object.get()),const char(&)[21]>::value`

Comment: NathanOliver,  `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(object.get()),const char(&)[21]>::value,"")`  it failed, also tried (just out of curiousity) `std::is_same<decay_t<decltype(object.get())>,const char[21]>::value` failed too.

Comment: @Explorer_N Are you using my example or yours?  `std::is_same<decltype(object.get()),const char(&)[3]>::value` works for my example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e88d9e5164850538

Comment: NathanOliver, you are right, there was a typo in my subscript value.